# SFML on Clion doesn't compile a window program

Tags: cmake, compilation, sfml, clion

```
Error: 
CMakeFiles\Aqu.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function main':
C:/Users/Admin/CLionProjects/Aqu/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'
C:/Users/Admin/CLionProjects/Aqu/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
C:/Users/Admin/CLionProjects/Aqu/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'
C:/Users/Admin/CLionProjects/Aqu/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to sf::Window::display()'
C:/Users/Admin/CLionProjects/Aqu/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
C:/Users/Admin/CLionProjects/Aqu/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\Aqu.dir\build.make:105: Aqu.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:72: CMakeFiles/Aqu.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/Aqu.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: Aqu] Error 2
```

My CmakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Aqu)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -static-libgcc")
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)

add_executable(Aqu main.cpp)

set(SFML_ROOT "C:/Program Files/SFML-2.4.2")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${SFML_ROOT}/cmake/Modules")
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED graphics network audio window system)

if(SFML_FOUND)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES}             
${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
endif()
```

If I want to write a window program using `RenderWindow` I get this error. I am working in Clion, using MinGW.

My problem in project compiling. This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
using namespace sf;
int main(){
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(200, 300), "11");
    window.display();
    return 0;
}
```

doesn't compile with the above error.

Comment: And was SFML *found*? If you clear the CMake cache and rerun CMake, what is the output you get?

Comment: My problem in project compiling. This code: `#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
using namespace sf;
int main(){
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(200, 300), "11");
    window.display();
    return 0;
} ` Doesn't compilling with the error in my question.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, but SFML should supports CMake Targets. 
If so you should be able to link using sfml_window etc... 
Or if it has a better support, maybe with SFML::window ...

Comment: You don't need the `SFML_FOUND` check because the `REQUIRED` keyword in `find_package` will generate an error if `SFML_FOUND` is false.

You could use `message` to print the contents of the `SFML_LIBRARIES` and `SFML_DEPENDENCIES` to see what they contain.

Are you sure that you have static libraries for all the dependencies since you use the `-static` linker option?